# knex select result return to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I need to get `knex` select query result to a variable.

```
function getUserPlanDetailsWithOutCb(user_id) {
 var dataArr =[];
 knex('user_plans').select('*').where({ 'user_id': user_id }).then(function(result) {
     result.forEach(function(value) {
        dataArr.push(value)
     });
 //return dataArr;
 });
 return dataArr;
}

 var result = getUserPlanDetailsWithOutCb(12);
```

I have tried return value outside and inside of the call back in `knex`. For above code i got the result as **[ ]** 
For second one `(return inside callback)` i got the result as

```
{
   "isFulfilled": false,
   "isRejected": false
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i need to get the result of this query to a variable. Like, var result = getUserPlanDetailsWithOutCb(19);

Comment: @Pillai It's an asynchronous function, so you have to pass a callback. Or you can use async/await with promises.

Comment: Have a look at this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then

Comment: @WaleedIqbal what i need is to assign result to a variable. I need to use that variable again.

Comment: @AbhyuditJain    
   
**async function getUserPlanDetailsWithOutCb(user_id) {
  return await knex('user_plans').select('*').where({ 'user_id': user_id}).limit(10);
}

var payment_data =User.getUserPlanDetailsWithOutCb(user.user_id);**

But i got **_Promise { <pending> }_**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get your variable returned using Promises, do the following to the data retrieval function:

*And note: The `return knex(` returns the Promise object to the caller, and the `return dataArr` returns the value to the caller's `.then()` promise clause.*

```
function getUserPlanDetailsWithOutCb(user_id) {
  var dataArr =[];
  return knex('user_plans').select('*')
     .where({ 'user_id': user_id })
     .then(function(result) {
         result.forEach(function(value) {
            dataArr.push(value)
         });
         return dataArr;
     });
}
```

Call the function via:

```
var result;
var aPromise = getUserPlanDetailsWithOutCb(12)
    .then(function(result) {
        result = value;
    });
```

The `result` variable will be set when the `aPromise` resolves.

Calling the function using `var aPromise` will cause program execution to continue before the Promise is fulfilled and the `result` is set, which may not be what you want. So you can use `await` instead (as @Abhyudit Jain notes), but I haven't done that, so I would mess up the syntax for you if I tried.

Cheers! Gary.

Comment: when only returning one column, i believe this works as well:
```.select('oneColumn') .where({ 'user_id': user_id })  .then( val => { return val; } ) ``` - opinions?