# How can I get the value from a Knex query using max?

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I have a very simple Knex query against a MySQL table to find the maximum value of the `id` column:

```
const maxId = await knex('some_table').max('id').first()
```

But this returns a `TextRow` object with a single, oddly named property. From a `console.log`:

```
TextRow { 'max(`id`)': 99 }
```

Is there an easy way for me to get the value, or do I have to use object property notation like this:

```
const idValue = maxId['max(`id`)']
```

Comment: try this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558183/knex-select-result-return-to-a-variable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the easiest answer is to alias the result, as in the second example shown [here](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-max):

```
const maxIdQuery = await knex('some_table').max('id as maxId').first()
console.log(maxIdQuery.maxId)        // shows the value
```

Alternate syntax:

```
const maxIdQuery = await knex('some_table').max('id', { as: 'max_id' })
console.log(maxIdQuery[0]['max_id'])
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.