# Javascript : array does not retain value

Tags: javascript, cypress

In the below code snippet,

```
function retreive_data_from_UI() {
    let arr_rows = [];
    cy.get(constants.cssCustomerWoListViewTable).children().each(($rows, ind) => {
        arr_rows.push($rows.text());
        cy.log(ind);
        cy.log(arr_rows[ind]);
    });
    cy.wait(1000);
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        // I tried both separately pop() and accessing by index
        cy.log(arr_rows.pop());
        // or
        cy.log(arr_rows[i]); 
    }
    return arr_rows;
}
```

the value for *arr_rows[ind]* is printed within cy.get().children().each(() => {}) block but not in the for loop that follows it. Below is the output

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDwFv.png)

Can anyone point out where I went wrong ? I am using cypress for writing frontend tests.

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to build a custom command instead of a JS function. Put a `console.log()` after `arr_rows.push()` and another inside `for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){`, you will see the order of execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by using the suggestions in the ([Return from a promise then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then)) :

Created and returned a Promise. This way I was able to use the resolved value (this.result) in another function too.

```
function retreive_data_from_UI(){
  var result = [];
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    cy.get(constants.cssCustomerWoListViewTable).children().each(($rows, ind) => {
      result.push($rows.text());
    }).then(function(){
      this.result = result;
      for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cy.log(this.result[i]) // content printed here
      }
      resolve(this.result)
    });
  });
}
```

Using the value of this.result in another function

```
it('Test WO Sorting Ascending', () => {
    cy.get(constants.btnLmsWOSortAsc)
    .click()
    .then(function() {
      retreive_data_from_UI()
      .then(function(result){
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
          cy.log(result[i]); // content printed properly here too
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be, because you are declaring `let arr_rows`, meaning a block scope. You are trying to fill it in an anonymous function, which has its own scope and therefore its own `arr_rows`.

Declare `arr_rows` with `var arr_rows = []` and it should work.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for more details.

Comment: I modified the declaration to var arr_rows = [] in the above code, but still have the same issue

Comment: In that case that wasn't it :(, try adding arr_rows to the anonymous function