# await function() doesn't wait for function to complete so returns result as undefined

Tags: javascript

I call a function then output it's return value in console, like so:

```
Index.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    const { loggedInUser } = await checkLoggedIn(ctx)
    console.log('Data actually returned:')
    console.log(loggedInUser)
    return { loggedInUser }
}
```

Pretty straight forward...

The checkLoggedIn function is as follows:

```
export function checkLoggedIn(ctx) {
    ctx.apolloClient.query({
        query: GET_ME,
    })
        .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log('Data to be returned:')
            console.log(data)
            return { loggedInUser: data }
        })
        .catch(() => { return { loggedInUser: {} } })
}
```

Again, pretty straight forward. This is essentially an exact copy of this example: [checkLoggedIn()](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-apollo-auth/lib/checkLoggedIn.js) and [getInitialProps](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-apollo-auth/pages/index.js)

Now what I would expect to happen is that I should see the following in the console:

```
Data to be returned:
{ <DATA> }
Data actually returned:
{ loggedInUser: { <DATA> }
```

Instead, I see:

```
Data actually returned:
undefined
Data to be returned:
{ <DATA> }
```

Which makes zero sense as the function is returning the correct data, and it should await for this returned data before proceeding to the console.log.

Instead, it completely ignores the 'await' and doesn't even bother waiting for the function to return a value before continuing.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you missing resolve() instead of return?

Comment: @IonicBurger — No. There is no manually created Promise to resolve. Promise resolution is handled behind the scenes by the internals of `apolloClient`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`() => { return { loggedInUser: {} } }` is a function that returns `{ loggedInUser: {} }`. Ditto for the function inside `then`.

Thus, `checkLoggedIn` has no `return`. It should return the promise it constructs:

```
return ctx.apolloClient.query({
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only (usefully) `await` a promise.

The function `checkLoggedIn` has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

`undefined` is not a promise, so `await`ing it has no effect.

Change `checkLoggedIn` so it returns the promise.

Comment: You can `await` a non-promise. `await 43` evaluates to `43`. It just doesn't make much sense to do it.

Comment: It has return in both the .then() and .catch() though, so no matter what it should return a value?

Comment: See my answer. It returns from the anonymous callback function, not from `checkLoggedIn`.

Comment: @GCM — No. That isn't how returning a value from a callback works. If you want to return from `checkLoggedIn`, then `checkLoggedIn` itself needs a `return` statement.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should make checkLoggedIn an async function

Comment: Then its return value  becomes a promise that resolves immediately as `undefined` which isn't helpful.