# TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, push

I'm trying to push to /home if status==200 ok but it's giving me an error.

```
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const form = this.props.form;
     const { password, username } = this.state;
   let data = new FormData(); // creates a new FormData object
   data.append('username', form.getFieldValue('username'));
   data.append('password', form.getFieldValue('password'));
   axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/', data)
   .then(res=>console.log(res))
   .then(data => { if(data.status == 200){ history.push('/home');}})
   .catch(err=>console.log(err))

 };
```

It renders this:

```
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Comment: Why do you use .then second time?  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/', data)
   .then(data => { if(data.status == 200){ history.push('/home');}})
   .catch(err=>console.log(err)). This should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/', data)
    .then(res=>console.log(res))
    .then(data => { if(data.status == 200){ history.push('/home');}})
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

with

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/', data)
    .then(res => (res.status === 200) && history.push('/home'));
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

I would suggest not to use data keyword here, this will create ambiguity as your API result has data keyword in it.
Try always using triple equal to (===) in js comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you cant read `data.status` is that `data` is undefined.

To get the data and the status, you need to return `res` so it's accesible in the next `.then`

Change this

```
.then(res=>console.log(res)) // data comes from the return of this function
.then(data => { if(data.status == 200){ history.push('/home');}})
```

To

```
.then(res => { 
    console.log(res)
    return res // data comes from the return of res
 }) 
.then(data => { if(data.status == 200){ history.push('/home');}})
```

If you aren't return something from `.then`, the next `.then` function parameter will be undefined.

Paraphrasing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43155226/9119186)

> When you return something from a then() callback, it's a bit magic. If you return a value, the next then() is called with that value.

In your case, you are returning `console.log(res)` wich don't have `status` property

Answer (score 0):

Replace your url :
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login/'
to
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login'

tell me if it works

Comment: The question is already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56256315/10983010