# Cypress: Finding number of elements without throwing error

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to find the number of elements present on a web page with a given locator(cy.get() or cy.xpath()). If the element is not present with the given locator, then it should not Fail the test.

I have tried cy.get(), cy.find(), cy.xpath(): all of them fails the test in case the element is not found on web page.
I have tried to use cy.get('body').find('loc').length;
But it also fails the test.

The below code works, but i am not able to use the value of x out side the loop. And scenario is as such that i cant put all of my code inside then().

```
let x = 0;
 cy.get("body").then(($body) => {
 x = $body.find("element").length;
 cy.log(`inside then: `,x);
})
cy.log(`outside then: `,x);
```

Expected:
inside then: ,1
outside then: ,1

Actual:
inside then: ,1
outside then: ,0

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `.its()` function to retrieve a value of `length` property:

```
cy.get("body").its("length");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur input. I tried this too. In case the element is not present then it gives the following message in Browser developer console : "Unhandled rejection CypressError: Timed out retrying" ..... but the execution stops here and the  further steps are not executed and the timer on the cypress left UI keeps on running . i have set all the timeouts to 30 secs.

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = 0;
 cy.get("body")
.then( 
  ($body) => {
  x = $body.find("element").length;
  cy.log(`inside then: `,x);
})
.then( 
  () => {
  cy.log(`outside then: `,x);
} )
```

You need to wait for the x update at x = $body.find("element").length;  
The eventloop looks like : 
1. let x = 0;  
2. cy.log('outside then: ',x);  - x =0;  
3. x = $body.find("element").length;  
4. cy.log('inside then: ',x);

Comment: agreed. but i tried to put cy.wait() outside then(), so that the code inside then() completes. But still the value of x is coming as 0 only. It executed in this sequence: let x=0 > x = $body.find("element").length; > x = $body.find("element").length; > cy.wait() > cy.log('outside then: ',x);

Comment: you should post bigger code snippet to see whats wrong there

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you want to achieve but I assume you want to test the total no of elements available. And if none then should not through error. If this is correct then this might help:

```
let x = 0;
function anyName() {
  return cy.get("body").then($body => {
    x = $body.find("element").length;
    if (x > 0) {
      cy.log(`Total no of elements found: ${x}`);
    } else {
      cy.log("Element is not available");
    }
  });
}
anyName();
```

Comment: thanks. But i need the value of x as return from the function. So that it can be used outside the loop as well.

Comment: Please refer here to return: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then