# JavaScript: returns variable as undefined in function

Tags: javascript

I'm wrote a function (with the help of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRiQeo17u6c) to geocode addresses using google maps. I want the function to return coordinates of any given address. Eventually, I'm hoping to write a script that loops over an array of addresses and returns a array of their coordinates in the form of `[lat, lng]`.

However, before we go to fast, this question is simply about returning one value. Please see the script below.

The function works. If I for example call `geocode('New York')` and enable `console.log(latlng)` within the function, it properly logs `[40.7127753,-74.0059728]`. However, if I call the function to appoint a variable like `var coord_address_1 = geocode("New York")` this variable is undefined. What am I doing wrong? I have read these posts [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and concluded that it has probably to do with the fact that I want `latlng` returned before it is assigned. However, as I am new to JS I didn't really understand how to avoid this. I tried around with `.then(function(latlng) {return latlng;})` and `callback(latlng);` but no luck there either (`ReferenceError: callback is not defined`).

```js
    <script>
      function geocode(address) {
        axios
          .get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", {
            params: {
              address: address,
              key: "API_KEY"
            }
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            // create variable in desired format
            var latlng =
              "[" +
              [
                response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
              ] +
              "]";

            // this works
            // console.log(latlng);

            return latlng;

          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }

      var coord_address_1 = geocode("New York");
      console.log(coord_address_1); // undefined
    </script>
```

Comment: This question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call ) is indeed the way to go. Yours will likely be closed because it's a duplicate, it's the exact same problem. This question was asked by pretty much everyone learning JS and stumbling upon asynchronism.

Comment: Either return the promise, or pass in a callback and invoke that with the values.

Comment: Basically, instead of `return latlng` which returns the value to nothing (dead end), pass the value to another function. `doSomethingWith(latlng)`

Comment: Imagine that `geocode("New York")` takes 3 seconds. Javascript is non-blocking, meaning it's not going to block the whole script for 3 seconds waiting for the answer. It jumps _immediately_ to the next line `console.log()` which logs undefined, because the instruction above is far from complete. It will be complete in 3 seconds, and you will have your result in the `.then()`. Returning the value won't do anything, it's too late. You need to pass it forward. Welcome to asynchronism :)

Comment: Alright guys, thanks for your quick responses! Ill have another go at understanding asynchronism :)  So it's not as simple as adding `.then(function(latlng) {return latlng; })` between the first `.then()` and the `.catch()`?

Answer (score 0):

When using a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), since the `.then()` is technically a method of the promise, any `return` inside the method actually returns for the `.then()` method, not the function outside.

Someone else had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34094806/9063935).

If you want to return the value from the function, you have to have your return statement outside of the promise's `.then()` or `.catch()` methods.

Another thing you need to consider is that the promise will not return immediately as it is asynchronous, [link from Jeremy Thille's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)