# Create a new array of documents of objects using map JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have an array of ids and I am trying to map through this array to create a new array of movie objects which is in my database.

my code looks like this...

```
const movieIds = foundDirector.movies;

const movies = movieIds.map(async (id) => {
    await Movie.findById(id);
  });
```

The code above doesn't work. I am able to find a movie and see that data from within the map function but when I print movies to the console I get an array with empty objects.

I then decided to do this instead and it works.

```
const movieIds = foundDirector.movies;
let movies = [];

for (let i = 0; i < movieIds.length; i++) {
  const movie = await Movie.findById(movieIds[i]);
  movies.push(movie);
}
```

I'm not happy with the solution. I obviously am having issues understanding how promises work in JavaScript and using `async/await` has been easy enough for now but I don't want to rely on it.

as an example I tried doing something like...

```
const movieIds = foundDirector.movies;
let movies = [];

for (let i = 0; i < movieIds.length; i++) {
  const movie = Movie.findById(movieIds[i]).then((data) => data);
  movies.push(movie);
}

const allMovies = Promise.all(movies).then((values) => values);
```

I noticed that after printing movies to the console I was getting an array of pending promises I tried using `const allMovies = Promise.all(movies).then((values) => values);` but `allMovies` still just is a pending promise.

Can anyone please explain what is going on here, and how can I achieve this with a map function rather than a for loop.

Comment: What about `const allMovies = await Promise.all(movieIds.map(Movie.findById))`

Comment: I think you can find your response [Use async await with Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140562/13212908)

Comment: Yes that works, of course it still is using await, so I guess from my understanding and further research, without using await I can only access the actual values within the `then`. Before looking at all the answers I ended up just doing `Promise.all(movies).then((data) => res.json(data))` to try to get it without await. Is this the reason why `async/await` was created. Quite honestly it is extremely annoying that without await we can't have a variable that holds these values without a pending promise. Await is cool and all but I just want to make sure I really understand this is how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can achieve what you want with an approach like below.

```
const allMovies = await Promise.all(movieIds.map(Movie.findById))
```

It just maps ids to promises and awaits all of them.

```
const allMovies = Promise.all(movies).then((values) => values);
console.log(allMovies);
```

The above code will log awaiting promises because by the time that `console.log` nothing has happened yet. There is nothing that awaits those promises to have resulted. Then callback has no effect on `allMovies` variable. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43155226/12354911) has nice info about it.