# Role member count function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made a function that supposed to return a role member count but it returns "undefined".

Here's my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', (message) => {
    argument = message.content.split(' ');
    switch (argument[0]) {
        case 'showmember':
          let membercount = (therole) => {
            let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === therole);
            message.guild.members.fetch().then(fetched => {
              let total = fetched.filter(m => m.roles.cache.some(r => r === role));
              return total.length;
            });
          };
          message.channel.send(membercount(argument.join(',').slice('showmember'.length)));
        break;
    }
}
```

This is what it says on the console `(node:133436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message`

Comment: Why is show member at the end in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it returns "undefined" is because .fetch() is a promise and thus your function called `membercount` does not immediately return a value. In fact, `membercount` doesn't even return a value. You can refer to [Return from a promise then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then) for why. Solution to this is just replacing `return total.length` with `message.channel.send(total.length)`.

Additionally, I have to point out that `message.content.slice('showmember'.length)` would be an empty string. The problem lies with your switch statement `switch (message.content)` because your case statement would be looking for an exact match `message.content === 'showmember'`. What you want to do instead is to check if message.content starts with 'showmember'. I recommend replacing your switch-case statement with `if(message.content.startsWith('showmember')` or something of similar logic.

Comment: Also is there a way for it to return total member?

Comment: `Object.keys(fetched).length` will give you the total number of members in the guild.