# My function call does not return the value

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, return

This is my code, i'm getting the values printed in console, but it's not returning that value.

```
async function fetchData(uid) {                                           
  return firebase.firestore().collection('users_info')
         .where("uid","==",uid).get()
         .then( async function(querySnapshot) {
             var usr;         
             querySnapshot.forEach(async function(doc) {           
             usr = await doc.data().name;
             console.log(usr);
             return  usr;
         });      
    });       
}
```

Comment: `return` in your promise callback function only returns the callback but not `fetchData`

Comment: `.forEach()` typically ignores the return value of the callback.

Comment: If you're going to declare a function `async`, then there is no need to use `then` for the promises inside it.  That's what `await` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a forEach I am assuming you are dealing with more than one data item. In that case, it might be better to push them all into an array and return that.
I am adding a slight modification of your snippet bellow. I think this should do the trick.

```
  async function fetchData(uid) {
    return firebase.firestore()
      .collection('users_info')
      .where("uid", "==", uid)
      .get()
      .then(async function(querySnapshot) {
        var usr = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(async function(doc) {
           const temp = await doc.data().name);
          usr.push(await doc.data().name))
        });
      return usr;
    })
  }
```

Comment: it's working , need to fix some small syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Two things - first, you need to return a promise, if your function itself is doing async work that needs it's own callback to be continued from. See [Return from a promise then()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34094806/1399272).

Also, foreach is not necessarily used to return a collection of transformed values, which seems to be what you're trying to do there. I'd replace it with map if you can.