# Calling a javascript function inside another function is considered undefined

Tags: javascript

I have created a function `getExchangeRate()` to get the current exchange rate of a country. Then I'm calling the function inside another function to get the current exchange rate for a particular country. But the function `getExchangeRate()` is considered `undefined`.

```
   getExchangeRates = function(x) {
  fetch('https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/547f5391104d30d830f55442/latest/SEK')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
    const ex= data.conversion_rates;
    return ex.x;     //Get the exchange rate for the respective country

  }).catch(function (error){
    console.error('Something went wrong');
    console.error(error);
  });

}

getCityInformation = function(city) {
  fetch('json/countries.json')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
    for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].city == city){
        console.log([data[i].city, data[i].countryName, data[i].currency, data[i].exchangeRate]); 

        let currentExchange_rate = getExchangeRates(data[i].currency);    // function is considered undefined

        let output = '<h2>Details of the city</h2>'
        output +='<ul><li>City Name:  '+ data[i].city +
          '</li><li>Country Name:  '+ data[i].countryName +
          '</li><li>Currency:  '+ data[i].currency +                  //   '</li><li>Currency:  '+ currentExchange_rate +  
          '</li><li>Exchange Rate:  '+ currentExchange_rate +
          '</li>'                  
        '</ul>';

        document.getElementById('contents').innerHTML = output;
      }     

    }
  }).catch(function (error){
    console.error('Something went wrong');
    console.error(error);
  });

}
```

Data return from:

```
fetch('https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/547f5391104d30d830f55442/latest/SEK')
```

```
{
   "result":"success",
   "documentation":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs",
   "terms_of_use":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms",
   "time_last_update_unix":1604016243,
   "time_last_update_utc":"Fri, 30 Oct 2020 00:04:03 +0000",
   "time_next_update_unix":1604102763,
   "time_next_update_utc":"Sat, 31 Oct 2020 00:06:03 +0000",
   "base_code":"SEK",
   "conversion_rates":{
      "SEK":1,
      "AED":0.4149,
      "ARS":8.8436,
      "AUD":0.1599,
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `getExchangeRates` does not `return` anything

Comment: I don't see `getExchangeRate` anywhere, do you mean `getExchangeRates`? Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: It's not saying that the function name is undefined, it's saying that the value returned by it is undefined. Since it doesn't have a `return` statement, it returns `undefined` by default.

Comment: Use `console.log` looks like you don't get inside your JSON data correctly. Inside `getExchangeRates` ==> `ex.x` - No way to return object data like this (`x` is a var). `return ex.x;` ==> change to `return ex[x];`

Comment: reserByra-model.js:50 ReferenceError: getExchangeRates is not defined
    at reserByra-model.js:34

Comment: @Bergi , if you check properly inside the function getExchangeRates, it returns ex.x.

Comment: @Ezra Siton, i've changed the return to ex[x], but still get the same error.

Comment: @DanAroka If you check properly, that is a `return` statement of the `then` callback function, not of `getExchangeRates`.

Comment: @Bergi, where then can i place the return?

Comment: Also, your issue related to the return value from a promise (Clean up your code first and try to return correctly simple "`Hello world`" message). Maybe helpful: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining ////////// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then

Comment: You need to place another `return` in front of the `fetch(…` so that you are returning your promise chain. Notice that you cannot synchronously return the conversion rate, you'll return a promise and will have to wait for it in your `getCityInformation` function

Comment: @Bergi, i had a seperate asyn-wait fetch function that returns a promise, then calling it in the getExchangeRates(). 

async exchangeRates() {
       let promise = await fetch('https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/547f5391104d30d830f55442/latest/SEK')
       return promise;
    }

    getExchangeRates = function(x) {
        exchangeRates()
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
                 let ex= data.conversion_rates;
                 console.log(ex);
                 return ex[x];     //Get the exchange rate for the respective country

Comment: @Barmar, yes it's getEchangeRates(). Error message is : reserByra-model.js:55 ReferenceError: getExchangeRates is not defined