# Undefined output from listObjectVesrsions even if i use promise

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sdk

```
list_versions: async (bucket, key) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      Prefix: key
    };
    const listObjectVersionsPromise = s3.listObjectVersions(params).promise();
    await listObjectVersionsPromise
      .then((data) => {
        return data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.stack);
      });
  }
```

If i print the outcome it is showing "undefined"
what might be the problem.

Comment: You're not returning the outcome of `await listObjectVersionsPromise...`.

Comment: There's not much reason to use `await` with `then`/`catch`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return from a promise then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then)