# When call ReadJson function , return undefine data variable, what is the solution?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

[js code to read data from mysql database using Get method ,but when call ReadJson function the result appeared un define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EesB5.jpg)

Comment: Don't post images of code. Just post the code itself. Wrapping it in 3 backticks will format it as well. Also don't tag php and Laravel because your question is only about your JS code. Whether or not the JS code accesses a PHP backend or one in any other language is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't return a value from callback function, you probably need to assign a value to a varaible outside the function.
[Return from a promise then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then)