# Return a composite object that contains a promise from a .then

Tags: javascript

What happens when I return a promise from a `.then` method which is wrapped in another object like:

```js
somepromise
.then((step1Result) => {
  return {
    'val1' : synchronousCalculation(),
    'val2' : asyncCalculation() // << THIS HERE
  };
})
.then((result) => {
  // PATH2
});
```

i.e. is `PATH2` guaranteed to have a settled promise in `result['val2']`?

A simpler situation is always guaranteed as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094806/return-from-a-promise-then) where the top answer mentions this [article](https://web.dev/promises/#queuing-asynchronous-actions):

> When you return something from a then() callback, it's a bit magic. If you return a value, the next then() is called with that value. However, if you return something promise-like, the next then() waits on it, and is only called when that promise settles (succeeds/fails)

Note that I'm avoiding to call `await asyncCalculation()` because I cannot turn the whole method into `async`, there's too much that would have to change if I did that.

Comment: No, not in this case as you are returning an object with a promise in it, which in itself is not a promise. If you turn that thrn function async and await the internal async, then yes, since you returned a promise which resolves to an object.

Comment: @somethinghere Could you show an example of how to do this. E.g. could I declare `async resultWrapper() : Promise<any> { return { /* object spec with member two as promise*? }; }` and then call that in the first `.then` branch ?

Comment: Basically add `await` before `asyncCalculation()` and also before `(step1Result) => ...` will turn your return value in a Promise, which, when received as a return value of a `then` callback, will return a new Promise with the new value chained. The next `then` in the chain will then only be called when the `asyncCalculation` completes, and the object in that then will be your object as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `Promise.then( callback )`'s `callback` returns a `Promise` itself, the next chained then will await that promise. So in order to be sure all your values are resolved, you would need to turn your callback async itself.

```
somepromise
.then(async step1Result => {

  const result = {
    'val1' : synchronousCalculation(),
    'val2' : await asyncCalculation()
  };

  return result;

})
.then(result => {
  // This `then` now resolves to the object
  // PATH2
});
```

An `async` function basically returns a `Promise` that resolves whenever all `await` statements have been resolved. And returning Promises inside `then` will chain them together. Consider this example:

```js
async function delay( d ){

  console.log( `Delaying by ${d}ms` );
    
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, d));
  
}

delay( 1000 )
  .then(() => delay( 1000 ))
  .then(() => delay( 1000 ))
  .then(() => {
  
    console.log( `Delayed by 3000ms, because all promises chain` );
  
  });
```

You can see that after resolving the first one, the `then` from that promise gets called. But `then` does not return the *same* promise:

```js
async function delay( d ){

  console.log( `Delaying by ${d}ms` );
    
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, d));
  
}

const step1 = delay( 1000 );
const step2 = step1.then(() => delay( 1000 ));
const step3 = step2.then(() => delay( 1000 ));

step3.then(() => {
   
   console.log( step1 === step2 ); // False
   console.log( step2 === step3 ); // False
   console.log( `Every time a new promise got made!` );
  
 });
```

Every time a new Promise is returned than get's awaited. So internally, you can nest as many promises as you want. If a Promise is returned, the next step in the chain will await it being resolved, if a value is returned, the next step just gets executed with that value.

Answer (score 3):

> What happens when I return a promise from a .then method which is wrapped in another object

The same thing as with any other value of a property of that object, it is not treated in any special way.

> i.e. is PATH2 guaranteed to have a settled promise in result['val2']?

No, there is no guarantee about that, `result['val2']` holds a promise that could be in any state.

What you could do is something like this:

```js
function synchronousCalculation() {
  return 1
}

function asyncCalculation() {
  return Promise.resolve(2)
}


Promise.resolve(0)
.then((step1Result) => {
  return Promise.all([
    synchronousCalculation(),
    asyncCalculation()
  ]);
})
.then(([val1, val2]) => {
  console.dir(val1)
  console.dir(val2)
});
```

like that:

Answer (score 1):

No, the `Promise` is not guaranteed to be resolved. Supposing that `synchronousCalculation` and `asyncCalculation` both take `step1Result` as the only argument, you could refactor your code like this:

```
const synchronousCalculationResult = somepromise.then(synchronousCalculation);
const asyncCalculationResult = somepromise.then(asyncCalculation);

const fullResult = Promise.all([
  synchronousCalculationResult,
  asyncCalculationResult,
]).then(([val1, val2]) => ({
  val1,
  val2,
}));
```